# How to get p50FileSize from OPTIMIZE (with no use of history)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I want to get the p50FileSize metric from after a OPTIMIZE query returns. Currently it seems the only way to accomplish this is along the lines of:

```
spark.sql("OPTIMIZE .delta 'path'")
dt = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, 'path')
```

Then get the history and operations from `dt`
A quicker way would be to pull this data immediately after the query:

```
data = Spark.sql("OPTIMIZE .delta 'path'")
```

And grab metrics from data, but there are no metrics for p25FileSize, p50FileSize, p75FileSize. Is there a way to get these metrics without calling the .history() command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get these metrics without calling the .history() command?

**tl;dr** No (Delta Lake 1.2.1)

### Internals

It looks like the [metrics](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/8b63a943d7aecff78962cda7a4f8973b584db7a2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/commands/OptimizeTableCommand.scala#L142) are calculated only for the transaction to be committed and are not given back when `OPTIMIZE` is executed.